# Stingiest browser when it comes to cross browser compatability

Tags: html, web

I know this is an opinion based question but I am hoping to dodge being closed because its not a personal taste question.

Which browser should i develop against that will show me that my code is most likely compatible across browsers?  In other words, Which browser is the most strict on code?  i.e. chrome seems to be the least strict..

My experience recently has been 0 bugs in chrome = 49 bugs in IE. I was wondering if I develop against IE would it be something like 0 bugs in IE = 11 bugs in chrome?

Answer (score 1):

Using one specific browser to try and see how compatible it is with other browsers just doesn't really make sense. You should develop in a modern browser using standards compliance and best practises and then test in all browsers to ensure cross browser compatibility and graceful degradation in older browsers.

Google Chrome and Chrome Canary are widely considered the best browsers to develop with but modern versions of Safari and Firefox are also good.

Answer (score 0):

You should develop for as many browsers as you reasonably can or want to target. Browsers aren't ordered by stringency; they each have their own quirks and oddities when it comes to the standards. So, assuming that something works in one browser (even the "most stringent") doesn't guarantee anything about what it looks like in another.

Answer (score 0):

Standard code will work on any major browser. I develop on chrome and then check it against Internet Explorer. IE used to be terrible at being standards compliant but is much better in recent releases.

If it works in IE 7 or 8 without any IE hacks then it should work everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

[Lynx](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lynx_%28web_browser%29).

It's still in active development. Still has a small user-base. And it doesn't support JavaScript, Flash, images, or video.

**If it works in lynx, it works on any remotely recent browser.**

---

If you're not concerned with that level of compatibility, you're *generally* safe developing for the lowest popular version of IE among your site's visitors, using [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/) or some other non-Microsoft reference as your resource (so as to avoid using IE-only features).

Answer (score 0):

Of you use a framework like Twitter bootstrap and jquery then it should look the same in all browsers. And it would be easiest to keep up to date.

Answer (score 0):

Well,

I call it not for nothing **Internet Exploder**. IE is a major pain in the ass, especially IE7 and 8. If you can get it working there, well lad, than you are ready for big projects.

Besides, check your site stats (with Google Analytics perhaps) and see which browser your users are using.